# I am getting this error. What is wrong?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift

I get the below error. Why do I get it?

> Duplicate symbol _main in:
>       /Users/AlexBomnd/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Backpack-gcnxteerautalugwepzkevaqgtxe/Build/Intermediates/Backpack.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Backpack.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.o
>       /Users/AlexBomnd/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Backpack-gcnxteerautalugwepzkevaqgtxe/Build/Intermediates/Backpack.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Backpack.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/AppDelegate-2D6246B5E95B9D9F.o
>   ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker
>   command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Answer (score 1):

Both `main.m` and `AppDelegate.m` (or perhaps `AppDelegate.swift`) contain the function `main`. Only one `main` function can exist per program, as it's the sole entry point for any C, Objective-C, or Swift program.

More information:

Compilation of a program is actually a series of a few separate steps.

Each project is composed of a series of *compilation units*. In Objective-C, each `.m` file is a compilation unit. In C, it's it's `.c` file. In Swift, the combination of all `.swift` files is one module (equivalent to a compilation unit for the others). Each of these is compiled independently, to produce a series of object files (`.o`, as you see in your error).

Your program has compiled and successfully made it past this step.

After compilation of the individual compilation units, the produced object files are *linked*  together by a program called the *linker*, to produce the file program. During the linking step, the linker runs into an error because both the `main.o` file (the object compiled from `main.m`) and the `AppDelegate-2D6246B5E95B9D9F.o` file (the object compiled from `AppDelegate.m` or `AppDelegate.swift`) contain a definition for the *symbol* `_main`. The linker doesn't know which of the two to choose, so it raises an error.